# Parallel API calls and updating an array of images as each call returns

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of IDs in react. For each of these IDs I need to make an API call to get a corresponding image url. The API calls can take a long time. How do I build the app so that the list of images is displayed asynchronously as each API call returns?

So far I've tried to use `array.map()` to call the API with `Promise.all()` to wait for all results. Then I'd use `setImageList([...results])` to update the state. This waits for all API calls to have returned. Can I change that so that the state gets updated as each API call returns?